# How to get the file type category in php

Tags: php, file-type

How could I get the file type category only?

For example:

```
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    echo $fileType;
```

In this code, it displays `image/jpeg`. Now what I want to get is only the `image` without the `jpeg.`

Same also with all of this:

Displays **image** only if the file type is:

- image/png
- image/gif
- image/bmp

and displays **text** only if file type is:

- text/html
- text/plain
- text/css

and so on, with the other file type..

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ? echo current(explode('/', $fileType))

Comment: @l0rkaY Please let me ask this one. Do you know some file preview plugin? because I want to have some gallery of my files. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not really... But write an own :)

Comment: Okay, anyways thanks.

Comment: But I think you can't preview an excel or a word document quickly... :(

Comment: Actually I have a plugin for uploading file which has a preview feature but i just don't know how to implement it in displaying files. hehe, nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, and may not work on all file types:

```
$type = explode('/', $filetype)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Accepting answers is the norm, but no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more or less what you mean.

```
list( $fileType, $junk )=explode('/',$_FILES['userfile']['type']);
```

Comment: what variable should i display here? would it be `echo $junk`?

Comment: no, you want $fileType - the $junk piece would refer to jpeg or whatever